# Uploading multiple image in dropbox ERROR(too_many_write_operations)

Tags: javascript, angularjs, ionic-framework, dropbox

Hi Im trying to upload an image to my dropbox and its working fine its uploading but when i choose a multiple image and upload it to the dropbox some of the images didnt upload and the error says

```
"{"error_summary": "too_many_write_operations/..", "error": {"reason": {".tag": "too_many_write_operations"}}}"
```

This is the code im using cordovafiletransfer

```
  $cordovaImagePicker.getPictures(optionsSelectImage)
            .then(function(results) {
                console.log(results)
                for (var i = 0; i < results.length; i++) {
                    // console.log('Image URI: ' + results[i]);
                    var image = results[i];
                    var counter = 0;
                    // var filename =  JSON.stringify(results[i].substr(results[i].lastIndexOf('/') + 1));
                    // console.log(filename)
                    var options = {
                        headers: {
                            'Content-Type': 'application/octet-stream',
                            'Authorization': 'Bearer ACCESS TOKEN',
                            "Dropbox-API-Arg": '{"path": "/photo.jpg", "mode": "add","autorename": true,"mute": false}'
                        }
                    }

                    $cordovaFileTransfer.upload('https://content.dropboxapi.com/2/files/upload', image, options)
                        .then(function(result) {
                            // Success!
                            counter++;
                            if (counter != results.length) {
                                $ionicLoading.show({
                                    //Loading Content
                                    template: '<ion-spinner icon="android"></ion-spinner><br><center>Uploading ' + counter + ' /' + results.length + ' to Dropbox</center>'
                                });

                            }

                            // if number of files uploaded in the dropbox == total number  of queued files for uploading
                            else if (counter === results.length) {
                                $ionicLoading.hide();

                            }

                            console.log(result)

                        }, function(err) {

                            // Error
                            console.log(err)


                        }, function(progress) {

                        });
```

I think the for loop is too fast for the process thats why dropbox api cant handle it? how can i slow it down or delay the upload for that

Comment: https://www.dropbox.com/developers-v1/core/bestpractices
_Rate limiting

The API limits the amount of calls your app can make per user. The limits are high enough that any reasonable use of the APIs shouldn't come close to hitting them. Apps that hit the rate limits will receive a 503 error which uses the Retry-After header to indicate exactly when it's okay to start making requests again. If your app uses OAuth 2.0, the error will be a 429 instead. If you keep hitting these limits, contact our developer support team and we'll work with you._

Comment: Note that `too_many_write_operations` in particular isn't explicit rate limiting. From the [Dropbox API v2 documentation](https://www.dropbox.com/developers/documentation/http/documentation#error-handling):
> too_many_write_operations Void There are too many write operations happening in the user's Dropbox. This is also known as "lock contention". You can find more information in the [data ingress guide](https://www.dropbox.com/developers/reference/data-ingress-guide).

Answer (score 0):

Probably you're uploading all at the same time, a better solution could be upload images by pairs or one by one, chaining the promises like this:

```
var promiseChain = Q.fcall(function() {});
results.forEach(function(filename) {
  var promiseLink = function() {
    var def = Q.defer();
    $cordovaFileTransfer.upload('...', filename).then(function(result) {
      // do stuff
      setTimeout(function(){
        def.resolve();
      }, delay) 
    });
    return def.promise;
  };
  promiseChain = promiseChain.then(promiseLink);
});

promiseChain();
```